# Set background color for 1/3 of the page in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a design in Boostrap 4 (alpha 5), and making one third of the screen having a pink background color. The background color should extend all the way from the left margin of my right column and to the right margin. The result should be a bit like:

[image]

Does anybody have any recommandations of best way of doing this?

Comment: you need to play with linear-gradient and media queries

Answer (score 3):

What if you use an gradient on the background for this?
See this example:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    lightgrey 0%,
    lightgrey 70%,
    hotpink 70%,
    hotpink 100%
  );
}
```

```html
your code
```

Comment: Although this might work, I was thinking of using the bootstrap classes for layout.

Comment: I extracted the needed part.

Comment: The problem here is on smaller screens, then the background still gets pink on one third of the screen, so even if works fine on md and larger, it does not work as intended on small mobile screens. Probably I need a media query as well?

Comment: please add a scribble or screenshot of your mobile view

Comment: Here is a codepen with code sample, and if you change the width I think the problem will be visible. https://codepen.io/losol/full/RoKWjR/

Comment: Here is your Code with mediaqueries: https://codepen.io/hillterence007/pen/ENZwqp

Comment: Thanks, but it does not scale well this either. So on some resolutions the gradient comes behind one of the text columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div on background with width set using  `vw`, which is [viewport width](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

For example:

```
.background{
    z-index: -1; // prevent "background" from covering anything
    width: 33vw; //give background width of one third of page
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* or absolute? I don't know what will be better for you */
    right: 0; /* stick to the right side */
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It is a bit in the right direction (at least with position: absolute), however it gives a bit of headache, and does not look good when scaling down on smaller screens.

Comment: Why does it look bad? It should always have 33% of the screen width no matter of screen size. I had small typo, there should be no space after `33`.